# resources.frontController.throwExceptions=1 does not generate exceptions

Tags: zend-framework

I'm setting `resources.frontController.throwExceptions = 1` (or true) in my `application.ini` but that doesn't seem to force the FrontController to throw exceptions.

I can see exceptions (output on the webpage) when I explicitly set  `protected $_throwExceptions = true;` in `Front.php` in Zend library.

Any idea why the config setting doesn't work?

Comment: When you say "see", do you mean output in the view, or whilst debugging? Also, explicitly setting "$_throwExceptions = false" is in contradiction to the first part - did you mean "$_throwExceptions = true"?

Comment: Yes, I meant $_throwExceptions = true, sorry about the confusion.
I see exception info output on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to have a stab in the dark and guess that you're using APPLICATION_ENV to determine the section the INI to load.

To see the exception messages in the view (i.e. on the web page), you need to be **displaying** exceptions.

By default, only the *development* section has `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1`

So, if this is the case, **APPLICATION_ENV** must be set to **development.**